# Getting the final projection from a wrapped IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services, expression-trees

I'm not really sure how to express what I'm trying to achieve without showing some pseudo-code to the effect -

Assuming the following DTO is defined:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

We have 2 different custom `IQueryable<T>` classes defined:

```
public class InnerQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    // ...
}

public class OuterQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    public OuterQueryable(IQueryable<T> inner)
    {
        // Assign `inner` to a local variable to be used in `IQueryable<T>` impl.
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

*NOTE: `OuterQueryable<T>` is designed to extend the behavior of any other `IQueryable<T>` type by wrapping it.*

And a rather naive extension method to allow `OuterQueryable<T>` implementations to be created simply:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ToOuterQueryable<T>(this IQueryable<T> inner /*, ... */)
{
    // Assume `OuterQueryable<T>` has a constructor that takes another `IQueryable<T>`.
    return new OuterQueryable<T>(inner /*, ... */);
}
```

Given an expression as shown below, is there any way for the `InnerQueryable<T>` instance to find out which specific properties are selected once the query is wrapped by `OuterQueryable<T>`?

```
InnerQueryContext.AsQueryable<Person>().Where(p => p.Age > 30)
    .ToOuterQueryable().Select(p => new
    {
        p.FirstName,
        p.LastName
    };
```

Is there anyway for `InnerQueryable<T>` to know that the query built on 
`OuterQueryable<T>` returned only `Person.FirstName` and `Person.LastName`?

If it helps to show the context, I have a WCF data service that returns our internal entity, but I need the ability to know which specific members of the internal entity were returned from the service. WCF DS defines the `OuterContext<T>` in this case and I haven't identified a way to intercept the response post-projection to tell me what I'm looking for.

Any ideas would be welcome.

---

UPDATE: What are `InnerQueryable<T>` and `OuterQueryable<T>`?

The answer to that is fairly involved if you aren't familiar with the architecture of WCF Data Services, but here it goes:

In WCF Data Services, a service exposes `IQueryable<T>` properties to a DataServiceProvider implementation (i.e. `EntityFrameworkDataServiceProvider`, `ReflectionDataServiceProvider`, or a custom `DataServiceProvider` implementation that implements the necessary interface(s)).

These core `IQueryable<T>` properties act as the foundation of resources exposed through the service, and are built upon using the composable nature of LINQ queries. A simple example using the `Person` entity above would look like:

```
public class SimpleContext
{
    public IQueryable<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] {
                new Person { FirstName = "George", LastName = "Jetson", Age = 43 },
                new Person { FirstName = "Elroy", LastName = "Jetson", Age = 7 }
            }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

This `SimpleContext` would then be referenced by a simple data service implementation:

```
public class SimpleDataService : DataService<SimpleContext>
{
    // InitializeService method and others...
}
```

Now when I query the data service passing a projection:

```
http://localhost/SimpleDataService/People()?$select=FirstName,LastName
```

The framework will take the `IQueryable<Person>` returned from `SimpleDataContext.People` and pass it through an internal `IQueryProvider`/`IQueryable` implementation that understands how to generate an expression tree from the query string parameters and then compose another query using the `IQueryable<Person>` as its source.

Conceptually though, my original question above describes how to replicate the behavior without having to worry about all of the WCF data services stuff.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - And you're correct, the InnerQueryable cannot and will not know when or if it is wrapped. That is the twist, if you will, on the question.

Comment: What's **InnerQueryable** used for ?

Comment: I think it would help if you explained what exactly `OuterQueryable` is and what is its purpose.

Comment: @svick - Updated the question with more detail about `OuterQueryable`

Comment: @minhcat_vo - Updated the question with more detail about `InnerQueryable`

Answer (score 2):

I still don't quite understand why would WCF DS need that `OuterQueryable`. What it needs to do is to parse the query and then call your `InnerQueryable` based on that.

If there indeed is some kind of wrapper around your `InnerQueryable`, then it's entirely up to that wrapper to decide what your wrapper queryable will be able to see.

Consider two trivial implementations of the wrapper: if the wrapper simply forwards each method call to the wrapped object, then you will be able to see everything directly. On the other hand, if the wrapper doesn't do anything at all, then there is no way for you to observe anything at all.

Comment: While I agree that it may not be the best design, this is a pattern I've encountered quite a bit in code found in the community and within the framework. The outer `IQueryable` wrapper does actually do quite a bit to hide the specifics of WCF DS internal behavior, but that's as much a blessing as a curse when trying to do any sort of operation that depends on _what_ it does. I'll keep looking through the code and leave the question open for others to possibly provide insight in hopes that this isn't completely hopeless. Thanks for answering. +1 for the insight.